# How would I go about allowing a command only during a certain time window?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command only work during a certain time in discord.py, is there any way I can create a selection statement or use the asyncio functions? Here is some of my code:

```
 @client.command(pass_context=True)
 async def pick(ctx):
    oneto5 = str(random.randrange(1, 5))
    await client.say("You recived " + oneto5 + " fish")
```

**UPDATE**
Here is my updated code, but it seems to give me wonky output. It does not iterate properly.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pick(ctx):
sec = localtime().tm_sec
count = 0
print(sec)
while  (300 >= sec):
    if (1 <= lowFishRange <= 20):
        oneto5 = str(5)
        await client.say("You recived " + oneto5 + " fish")
        await asyncio.sleep(43200)
        return
    else:
        oneto5 = str(1)
        await client.say("You recived " + oneto5 + " fish")
        await asyncio.sleep(43200)
        return
else:
    await client.say("You seemed to have missed the mark, try again when a message appears...")
    await asyncio.sleep(43200)
    return
```

Comment: `tm_sec` is just going to be an integer in the range `[0, 61]`.  So `300 >= sec` is always going to be true.  What is the `300`?

Comment: just a numeric literal for 300 seconds. I guess I should use minutes rather. I think I can work around this. I will make a another post later if it does not work how I want it too. Also, thank you so much. You have helped me quite a bit. I owe you one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current time as a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) with [`localtime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.localtime). That gives you the local hour, minute, etc. You can then compare those against your target conditions.  If, for example, you want to only allow commands between 9 AM and 5 PM, you can do

```
from time import localtime

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pick(ctx):
   hour = localtime().tm_hour
   if 9 <= hour < 17:
       oneto5 = str(random.randrange(1, 5))
       await client.say("You recived " + oneto5 + " fish")
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can get it to reset once the user uses the command?

Comment: Are you looking for there to be some regular window of time in which people can issue commands, or are you looking for commands to have a cooldown period?

Comment: Well I am using tm_sec rather than tm_hour, and I need the sec variable which is essentially my loop control variable. (I changed my if statement to a while loop so it would iterate) to be set so that my loop evaluates as false. For example, 300 >= sec should evaluate as false after the user uses !pick command.

Comment: I can't quite picture what your saying.  Could you share some code?

Comment: Sure thing sorry,